# numpy array reshape returns a new array, rather than reshaping in place. Any design reason for that?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
a = np.zeros(3)
print a.reshape((3,1))
print a
```

> [[ 0.]
> [ 0.]
> [ 0.]]
>
> [ 0.  0.  0.]

It is a bit counter-intuitive that a.reshape does not change the shape of a. Is there any design reason for this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It creates a new array object, but does not copy the data in most cases. `a.base is reshaped.base` should be `True`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is actually possible to change an array object's shape instead of creating a reshaped view, you almost never actually need to do it, and it offers almost no performance difference relative to making a view.

Making a view reduces the risk that you'll mutate the shape of an object some other code needed, and it saves you from having to write `a[:].reshape(...)` instead of `a.reshape(...)` in the common case where you still need the original array with its original shape.

Almost no shape manipulation tool in NumPy will modify an object's shape in place, but if you really want to do it, you can, as long as the strides work:

```
a.shape = (3, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `reshape` frequently to make a test array, like this:

```
In [180]: x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [181]: x
Out[181]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

The inplace alternative is:

```
In [182]: x = np.arange(6); x.shape = (2,3)
In [183]: x
Out[183]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

I use the inplace method so rarely that I almost forget it's there.  In fact it is hard to think of common inplace operations.

```
In [185]: x.fill(0)
In [186]: x
Out[186]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

---

In addition to `x.reshape`, there's `np.reshape(x)`.  That is in `/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py`.  `fromnumeric` indicates that it was part of the `numeric` package, a predecessor of `numpy`.  So the approach goes way back in time.

Also the inplace `shape=` is more restrictive.

```
In [195]: xt = x.T
In [196]: xt.shape
Out[196]: (3, 2)
In [197]: xt.shape=(2,3)
...
AttributeError: incompatible shape for a non-contiguous array
```

Because the transpose reshapes, and changes the order (to 'F'), it can't be reshaped would doing violence to the underlying data.  `xt.reshape(2,3)` ends up making a copy, not a view.